# bulk update database host name for all cpanel accounts

Tags: mysql, database, ssh, sed, centos

I have migrated the MySQL databases to a remote server.
So my existing applications that are using the localhost database are now breaking.

To resolve this, i have edited /etc/hosts file as
123.123.0.0(remote-db-ip) localhost

Now while I am pinging the localhost from the server it is resolving to the remote IP.
But the applications are still resolving the local database server.

As my above attempt fails I need to change each of my (500+) PHP applications (mostly Wordpress and Laravel)database hostname automatically.

Comment: What is your actual question?

Comment: I want a bash script to search all wp-config.php file on the server and update/replace
this line 
define( 'DB_HOST', 'localhost' );
to
define( 'DB_HOST', 'db.***.net' );

or replace "localhost" to "DbHostName"